# Tweetie 2/Facebook-like swipe gesture in UITableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hey everyone, I was just wondering if anyone knows how to create a UITableviewCell swipe effect akin to the one in the Tweetie 2.0 app (see video: [Tweetie 2.0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oO8WYwYUD-o#t=01m14s)) or in the Facebook 3.0 app (when pressing the blue "+" next to a status).

What I need to do is to have the cell slide away in response to you swiping it and reveal a background view.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By the way, I did find this but it appears to place the background view in front of the cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933428/tweetie-like-swipe-menu

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259960/uitableviewcell-swipe-for-drawer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both Tweetie and Facebook implement their own 'custom' swipe detection. What I mean is that instead of using the standard `UITableView` hooks for swipes, you override `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, et.c in your own subclass of UITableView. You can then start detecting swipes yourself and call whatever methods you want on your UITableViewCell's. (Hint: to get the cell given an UITouch, use the UITableView method indexPathForRowAtPoint:)

There's also a another plus to managing your own swipes: you get a lot more control over how accurate each swipe needs to be.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. Would you happen to know how to display the background view as well?

Comment: You can just draw in the background view yourself when cell is swiped. Actually, you can do anything you like, really, with this approach :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I think I've got it now.

Comment: Wow indexPathForRowAtPoint <3!

Comment: Don't do this! Detecting your own gestures is coding suicide. Take a Look at UIGestureRecognizer : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: to be fair to the OP – UIGestureRecognizer wasn't public API at the time

Comment: I asked Tweetie's developer at the time, and Tweetie uses tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath: to detect the swipe and overrode -setEditing:animated: to do nothing. He does NOT do custom gesture recognition!