# UITableViewCell Swipe for Drawer

Tags: iphone, uitableview

This is really more of a curiosity than a hard coding question.

Both Facebook and Twitter both have a feature where swiping a UITableViewCell animates the cell off the side to reveal a drawer with more controls underneath. How is something like that accomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a great open-source method for doing exactly this, based on the behavior of the Twitter app:

https://github.com/thermogl/TISwipeableTableView

Comment: Well, it _almost_ worked for me. Unfortunately, that project uses deprecated methods for drawing. I'm in progress on a modern implementation, so maybe I'll post something when I'm satisfied with it.

Comment: You also find an example on how to detect swipe gestures on a UITableView on our blog http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=795

Comment: Should have accepted this 2 years ago. Good lord has it been that long?

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem I have tried a couple of different solutions to. I really liked the behavior of Mailbox (mailboxapp.com). So I set out to achieve this. In the end I ended up with what I believe is a very simple solution: use a UIScrollView inside your cell. I have blog [post](http://derrh.tumblr.com/post/49873350676/uiscrollview-the-workhorse-of-ios) that discusses and a [sample app](https://github.com/derrh/SwipeAwayCell) that demonstrates this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

## 2 ways to detect swipt action

1. look at the `willTransitionToState:` method of UITableViewCell.
   this method will be invoked when you swipe at the cell.
2. [Custom swipe detection in a TableViewCell](http://devblog.wm-innovations.com/2010/03/30/custom-swipe-uitableviewcell/)

and then you can change your cell view easily.

Comment: The swipe detection is the easy part. It's the sliding animation and showing a separate view that is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You could just implement `-tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view delegate.

[From the doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:),

> This method is called when the user swipes horizontally across a row; ... This method gives the delegate an opportunity to adjust the application's user interface to editing mode.

Comment: Doesn't this method also automatically add a delete button? I don't think DVG wants that, and I know I don't.

Comment: It automatically does whatever you provide for it in the delegate for the `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Comment: So if you return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` to that method, it will perform no automatic action, allowing you to do as you please :)

Answer (score 1):

As a `UITableViewCell` is just a `UIView`, you can use this fact to basically do anything you like with it.

To solve your problem, I'd attach a [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to detect the swipe and then animate the view to a different state.

For example, you could create a custom cell that has it's content view laying above the "actions view". Whenever there is a swipe, you use a UIView animation to move the content view aside and show the action view with a couple of buttons instead. In a custom UITableViewCell you could add a delegate protocol to have the pressed action and the cell being sent to the delegate, i.e. your controller. There you'd trigger what ever there is to trigger and then transition the cell out of the state.

Comment: Can subviews exist outside of a UITableViewCell's contentView? I couldn't get this method to work.

Comment: Yes, there can. The Delete button and the background views are just two examples.